# How to determine if width has px or %

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can i tell if a css property such as width ex: `width:100%` has px or % assigned to it. 
in chrome for example if i have `width:250px;` and i do `$('div').width()` i get `250` whereas if i use percentage, i just get the width in px for the percentage based on my screen resolution.

Comment: Say more about your scenario.  What do you need the information for; what will you do with the information?   It's my understanding that if you read the width via the DOM `style` object, you will get it in px. This does not mean the width was set in px.

Comment: by css property do you mean css rule or inline style?

Comment: Why is this important? How will you benifit from the knowledge?

Comment: @Esailija I'm referring to both inline and class

Comment: @Pinkie If you need from css class declared in stylesheets, check out my answer and let me know if you need the code for it because it's very unpractical to do it

Comment: @ash, i need to fill in the numeric value and measurement value of the element clicked on

Comment: @Esailija, sure if you have the code ready, post it.

Comment: @pinkie, to get the width in percentage the element must have 'display: none'. Check this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30251040/6705873

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work.

```
var value = $('#id').get(0).style.width;
var hasPx = value.indexOf('px') >= 0;
var hasPct = value.indexOf('%') >= 0;
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/asewit/2/edit#javascript,html

Comment: This isn't working for me. Can you show the example of jsfiddle.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/wc4m4/1/. Am i doing it wrong. It's alerting px instead of %

Comment: Yes. You're checking hasPct.length. It's not a string, but a boolean. Just do hasPct ? 'pct' : 'px'

Comment: True. But in your case if hasPct false value can be set in pixels, ems, points as well.

Answer (score 9):

If by "css property" you mean css rule, and not inline style property set directly in the element, there is no fast way to get it. You'd have to:

1. Query all css rule declarations
2. Loop through every css rule and check if the element matches the
       rule and push it into array
3. Loop through the candidates and take the latest width value, or the
       latest width value with !important

If you mean inline style, it's so trivial it's hard to understand why the question got so many upvotes:

`element.style.width` and check if there is a px or % there

edit: here is incomplete demo for the css rule querying:

http://jsfiddle.net/Chjnd/1/

tested in google chrome and firefox

Comment: To get the width in percentage, the element must have 'display: none'. This is a much simpler solution: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30251040/6705873

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.style.cssText`, which contains the actual CSS code:

```
$("<div style='width:50px'>").get(0).style.cssText // "width: 50px; "
$("<div style='width:50% '>").get(0).style.cssText // "width: 50%; "
```

Comment: I can't reference an element as you are showing in your example. i need to check for if `$('#id').width()` has px or %. How do i layout the syntax

Comment: @Pinkie: Well then it's `$("#id").get(0).style.cssText`.

Comment: problem with this approach is it will get more than one rule. i.e.: `$("<div style='width:50px;height:90px'>").get(0).style.cssText // "width: 50px; height: 90px; "`

Comment: i think it only works on inline styles, it won't pick up rules from the stylesheet: http://jsfiddle.net/SmFZe/