# How to get CSS of element (% vs px)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I create a DIV like this:

```
something = $("<div/>", { id: "something" }).css({
    width: "100%",
    background: "#333333",
    height: "3px",
    position: "relative",
    "-moz-box-sizing": "content-box"
});
```

And try to get the width with either of these:

```
console.log(something.width());
console.log(something.css("width"));
```

It just returns 100. For my scenario I will sometimes use a percentage or a specific number of pixels.

How can I determine if the width of the element is a percentage or specified pixel amount?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786972/how-to-determine-if-width-has-px-or

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the following returns the value with unit

```
alert(something.css("width"));
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/669QT/3/)

Or if the issue is occurring after the element is added to the DOM, it will still give in the value in terms of pixel

Comment: The problem with that is that when the element is added to the DOM, it return the value in px  : http://jsfiddle.net/669QT/4/

Answer (score 3):

Make use of [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
var w = something.css("width");
if (w.indexOf("px") != -1) {
    // Do something
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8RTMy/)**

When you append this to body the width will be in pixels. You can calculate the percentage by making use of [`$(window).width()`](https://api.jquery.com/width/) or retrieving the width from a parent container. Really depends on the application.

**[DEMO (calculate the percentage)](http://jsfiddle.net/7CUeE/)**